# Data syncing application between PC and Android?

Tags: java, android, web-services, synchronization

So I wasn't exactly sure what to search for when I needed an answer to this problem, hence the crappy title, so I'm sorry of this is a repeat Q but I was hoping for some suggestions on how I should approach the following project:

- An application similar to Google's [Chrome to Phone](http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/) but...

  - Much more functional
  - Much more scalable
  - Bidirectional (PC to phone and phone to PC)
  - Add in clipboard sync

    - Needs to be fast in order to be useful
  - Not a chrome extension but a PC application (Java?)

The way I initially wanted to go about it is creating a web service where clipboard data and other requests could be passed onto the phone or PC using polling but (and I'm not sure how accurate this is) this could seriously harm battery life on android if I'm polling every few seconds for clipboard data and if I'm conserving battery life by not polling as frequently, clipboard data becomes less available.

Any creative solutions? (or blatantly obvious ones that I'm not seeing)

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Hi, cool I just created an application that synchronizes clipboards between Android and Windows. Are you still working on this? Do you have something interesting already? Maybe we can share ideas or even team up. You can find my e-mail in my profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than polling, you should use [Android Cloud-to-Device Messaging](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) (C2DM).

Comment: Looks really promising. Thanks, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I just launched ClipboardSync, a Android app with a PC client that matches all your requirements. Check it out at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ClipboardSync.
It does't poll on the Android end, uses push messaging. The PC client polls for data updates but I'm working on an upgrade to something better for it.